# Simultaneously reassign values of two variables in c++

Tags: python, c++, variable-assignment, swap

Is there a way in C++ of emulating this python syntax

```
a,b = b,(a+b)
```

I understand this is trivially possible with a temporary variable but am curious if it is possible without using one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the standard C++ function `std::exchange` like

```
#include <utility>

//...

a = std::exchange( b, a + b );
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    std::cout << "a = " << a << '\n';
    std::cout << "b = " << b << '\n';

    a = std::exchange( b, a + b );

    std::cout << "a = " << a << '\n';
    std::cout << "b = " << b << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
a = 1
b = 2
a = 2
b = 3
```

You can use this approach in a function that calculates Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You could assign to [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) when there are more than two values to unpack. In python, you could do `a, b, c = 1, 2, 3`, which is not possible using `std::exchange`. [Vlad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70896991/12416453) answer is perfect for your use case. This answer is meant to complement Vlad's answer.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;

std::tie(a, b, c) = std::make_tuple(4, 5, a+b+c);
std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c; // 4 5 6
```

[Try it Online](https://godbolt.org/z/4znqK1ex5)